# Publishing large datafiles with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a project with a rather large datafile (30MB) and it seems that each time I publish the ClickOnce project it has to copy the datafile up to the server, even though it is a duplicate of the other duplicates that are up there.  Is there any way to avoid this outside of separately hosting the data file and downloading it in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this file out to a custom prerequisite package to solve this.  From your ClickOnce install you can check for this package and install it if needed. Here's [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to how to do it.

The prerequisite package only needs to be redeployed when it changes, saving you lots of upload time.

Comment: Is this going to add an extra dialog that the user has to click through?

Comment: The dialog appears only if its not already installed. If multiple prerequisites are needed I believe they are bundled into just the one dialog, so even then it may not be an extra dialog.